# Storing 3rd Party Credentials

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I am trying to make a HTTPS call to the Paypal PayflowPro gateway API. I need to pass the credentials along when I make the call. What is the best way for me to encrypt / decrypt the password for our account. I don't wanna hard code our password into my PHP script.

I have searched for things similar to this thread's title but I can't seem to come up with a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried the password will be sniffable, you can stop worrying, the SSL connection encrypts the sent data for you.

If you want to store the credentials in a configuration file, I can understand your concern. You can use some of the encryption methods to store the credentials in a encrypted form on disk and decrypt them before sending them to the paypal service.

If I'm correct you could use the MCrypt library in PHP to get this done. 
The possible cyphers are available here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Just make sure you don't use a (non-decryptable) hash algorithm like MD5 or SHA1, and remember the seed (key) you use to encrypt the data.